# Running all unittest.TestCase imported using from .. import *

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I have the following package:

- `tests.py`
- tests

  - `__init__.py`
  - `test_module_a.py`
  - `test_module_b.py`

In my `tests.py` file I do the following:

```
import unittest

from tests import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

In my `tests/__init__.py` the following:

```
__all__ = ["test_module_a", "test_module_b"]
```

In my `tests/test_module_a.py` and `tests/test_module_b.py` files, I have the following:

```
import unittest

class TestMyModule(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_something(self):
    self.assertTrue(True)
```

When I run `python tests.py`, the submodules seem to be imported but my `unittest.TestCase`'s are not run.  Why?  Thank.

Comment: Does test methods name starts with 'test'?

Comment: @biniow yup, if I import using `from tests/test_module_a import TestMyModule` it sees and runs the tests

Comment: In your current code you imorted `test_module_a` and `test_module_b` using `*` notation which is bound not to work. If you use `from tests/test_module_a import *` it will work

Comment: why don't you use unittest's discover. It will be easier for you

Comment: @ArpitSolanki that's why I have the `__all__` variable in the `__init__.py` specifying the submodules to import.

Comment: check in `tests.py` if you can instantiate this `TestMyModule` class

Comment: @ArpitSolanki no, I get a `NameError`, but I can write a print statement in the `test_module.py` files so it seems to run the test files.  that's why I'm so confused.

Comment: that's what I am saying. Module is imported but not the class. I suppose if you write `test_module_a.TestMyModule` in tests.py it will instantiate but it can not be discovered by unittests this way. I suggest go into tests directory and run `python -m unittest discover` and see if it works

Comment: @ArpitSolanki hate when you can't get clever =/

Comment: @believesInSanta sorry I didn't understand. DId I say something wrong or did something worked for you because of me?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki no, `python -m unittest discover` is a good suggestion.  thanks~  I'm just confused why `unittest` can't discover the `TestCase`'s.

Answer (score 0):

Use a test loader and import explicitly every test case (to be more readable) :

```
import unittest

from test_module_a import TestMyModule1
from test_module_b import TestMyModule2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    suite = unittest.TestSuite((loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMyModule1),
                                loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestMyModule2),
                                )
                               )
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2)
    runner.run(suite)
```

Comment: I don't think that really answers my question, but I hadn't seen any examples of `unittest.TestLoader` before since I'm quite new to python.